# Hover selects wrong line marker

Tags: highcharts, rendering

I have a chart using Highcharts that has a columnrange and a line series overlaying the column range. This is to show the High/Low & Average temperature.

When you hover over the range chart (but not the average marker) the Average temperature can sometimes be selected from another column, and an incorrect marker is highlighted. If you actually hover over the line marker the correct data is displayed for that column in the tooltip and the correct marker is highlighted.

The following fiddle shows this behaviour if you hover over 1974 and then move up/down the column over the average marker.

https://jsfiddle.net/5u7q0Lzt/

```
var i = Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'columnrange',
                    //        inverted: true
                },
                title: {
                    text: ""
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    columnrange: {
                        dataLabels: {
                            color: 'silver',
                            enabled: true,
                            className : 'smallLabel',
                            formatter: function () {

                                return parseInt(this.y) + '°';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                series: [

                {
                    name: 'Temperatures',
                    //pointWidth: 20,
                    data: [[3.3,20.2],[7.2,11.1],[-1.1,15.7],[0.6,14.4],[10.6,20.0],[5.0,18.0],[7.0,12.0],[3.0,14.0],[6.0,21.0],[3.0,15.0],[9.0,17.0],[10.0,11.0],[4.0,14.0],[2.0,13.0],[0.0,12.0],[4.2,12.0],[2.3,15.1],[1.3,15.1],[4.5,8.3],[2.8,17.0],[2.9,17.9],[2.4,19.5],[9.2,13.2],[1.0,15.0],[-0.2,17.8],[1.0,8.4],[3.0,15.2],[2.0,12.0],[11.0,19.0],[3.0,19.0],[0.0,13.0],[3.0,12.0],[14.0,21.0],[7.0,19.0],[6.0,11.0],[-1.0,13.0],[3.0,13.0],[4.0,9.0],[7.0,12.0],[-1.0,9.0],[2.0,20.0],[-1.0,15.0],[6.0,19.0],[9.0,15.0],[2.0,13.0],[6.0,14.0],[6.0,16.0],[-2.0,12.0],[8.0,11.0],[12.0,20.0]]
                },
                {
                    name : "Average",
                    type: 'line',
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidthPlus: 0
                        }
                    },
                    marker: {
                        enabled: true,
                        radius: 5
                    },
                    data: [7.5,9.1,9.8,3.7,11.7,10.3,9.8,8.7,14.2,8.8,13.0,10.3,8.2,6.7,5.6,7.3,11.9,6.9,6.5,8.2,9.9,9.6,10.4,7.2,9.9,4.8,8.9,6.8,15.8,11.4,6.3,7.9,17.6,11.5,7.7,7.1,8.2,6.5,9.4,4.6,10.7,5.2,12.1,10.8,8.9,8.6,11.2,5.0,9.9,15.1],
                    color: 'navy'
                }],                
                valueAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        format: "{0}"
                    }
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: 'Temperature ( °C )'
                    }
                },

                xAxis: {
                    labels: {
                        step: 3
                    },
                    categories: [1964,1965,1966,1967,1968,1969,1973,1974,1975,1976,1977,1978,1979,1980,1981,1982,1983,1984,1985,1986,1987,1988,1989,1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016]
                    },
                credits: { enabled : false },
                legend: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    crosshairs: true,
                    shared: true,
                    valueSuffix: '°C',
                    useHTML: true,
                    formatter: function() { 

                        points = this.points;// || Highcharts.splat(this);
                        return "<b>"+this.x+"</b> had a " + 'range of ' + points[0].point.low + '° to ' + points[0].point.high+"°C with an average of " + points[1].y + "°";
                    }
                },
                transitions: true,
            });
```

Is this a bug in Highcharts or something I have done by mistake? I can't see anything wrong so far. Both series have 50 points.

Comment: It seems that this issue doesn't occur anymore.